# Comparing n population proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, z-statistic

In the examples I am reading (which includes Stats for Dummies!!) most examples of null hypothesis testing reference 2 populations. However lets say I complete a survey and get the following results:

Which (UK) political party did you vote for and Which supermarket do you shop at:

1. `Conservative: 50% Waitrose, 20% Tesco, 10% Aldi, 10% M&S`
2. `Labour: 60% Tesco, 10% M&S, 30% Waitrose`
3. `Liberal: 10% M&S, 50% Sainsburys, 40% Tesco`

The null hypothesis is that there is no difference between which shops you buy from based on the party you voted for. How would I test that?

Comment: If you had the actual numbers then you could perform a chi-square test

Comment: I came across that. Is that the better solution then? Yes I would know the %s. Would ANOVA be applicable here?

Comment: Percentages are not numbers: it makes a difference as to whether your sample is 10 from each party or 10,000

Comment: I do not believe this can be done without knowing the number of people surveyed. Even then, there are issues like who will respond. Perhaps the people willing to answer are on the more extreme sides.

Comment: I would know the total numbers as well so I think a Chi squared is the best route

Comment: Please edit your question giving numerical counts instead of percentages.